# Physical Conditioning for Skateboarding

Tags: training, injuries, skateboarding

I've been thinking of taking up skateboarding again as an adult (I'm in my early thirties and its been at least 10 years since I popped an ollie) but I am concerned about being too out-of-shape. I'm not overweight and I do exercise regularly but I worry that a lot of the muscles used to do tricks have atrophied in the decade or so since my last kick-flip. I'm interested to know if anyone has had success with physical conditioning exercises specifically tailored to skateboarding. Can you recommend some stretches or exercises that helped your ability to do tricks and/or avoid injury after a long break from skating?

Comment: I'm torn on placing this question on hold. This question asks for exercise and fitness related to a specific, competitive sport. Moreover, we had [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12846/soccer-conditioning-at-older-age-to-prevent-injury) regarding playing soccer after a long layoff from the sport and being in shape. The question about soccer was received well, and this is the same question, only for skateboarding. Perhaps the recommendation request could be removed, and ask how one can prevent injury through conditioning wrt skateboarding after a long layoff?

Comment: I wouldn't call skateboarding a competitive sport, in the same way that running is not a competitive sport. If somebody asked how to avoid injuries while running in the park, we'd migrate to PF - if somebody asked how to avoid injuries while competing in middle distance races, that would be the competitive sport. This falls on the former category.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that will strengthen your lower body and core should be good.
Calf raises
Leg Press
Lunges/squats

Try doing some exercises that require balance as well, such as doing curls while balancing on one foot.

Comment: I didn't answer because I have 0 skateboarding experience, but in any sport, [having core strength decreases dependence on knees and ankles](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/13073), which leads to preventing injury on knees and ankles. I'm sure skateboarding has its quirks as does any sport, but this is a good start for anyone preparing to undertake a sport.

Comment: My experience isn't skateboarding either, but it is similar in that my sport is about knowing where your weight is in regards to wheels.  The older I get the more important maintaining flexibility has become.  You can't shift your weight if your hips no longer bend and rotate.  And you can't keep your weight low if the knees no longer bend that far.

Comment: Im asking for skateboarding-specific recommendations. Doing most tricks on a skateboard requires swift, snappy movements and puts a fair bit of stress on your ankles; maybe other joints as well.